# in java, what is the function of plus operator and x in the system.out.print(x + "+" + x + "=")?

Tags: java, variables, printing

So i was wondering, in order to print numbers that we just  entered,we have to assign certain variables.I'm using scanner. For example,i entered number 12, here it is the coding

```
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value of x");
        int x=in.nextInt();
        **System.out.print(x + "+" + x + "=");**
        System.out.println(x+x);
```

and this is the output

[image]

i just wondering why must put 2 addition symbols in (x + "+" + x + "=")??

Comment: Have no idea what you're asking. Why you have to assign your input to a variable?

Comment: That is one way to get the output you have displayed. `System.out.printf("%d+%d=%d%n", x, x, x+x);` is another. You could have more `print` statements too.

Comment: The addition symbols are used to concatenate the strings

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i see thank you that's all i want to know ,

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you!!! gonna keep it in mind

Comment: Would the downvoters please add a comment to explain how they think this question could be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` sign in java is "overloaded", which means that it has multiple meanings. In an arithmetic context - when it's applied to numbers - it means "plus", as you would expect. However, in a String context - ie, when it's applied to two Strings - it means "concatenate", or "string together".

For what follows, it is important to distinguish between numbers - the quantities which we perform arithmetic on and can represent in various ways - from the String representations of those numbers.

In your second expression `System.out.println(x+x);`, the plus sign means addition, since both of the arguments (`x` and `x`) are integers. Thus `x+x` evaluates to the integer `24`. Then, since we're printing this to the standard output, we have to understand it as a String, so Java converts the number `24` into the String `"24"`, and that is what is printed.

In your first expression `x + "+" + x + "="` all of the terms are understood as Strings, because Java does not know how to add an integer to a String, so it assumes you mean the String representation (`"12"`) of the number (`12`). Therefore the plus operator is understood to mean "string these together", and so it does: it evaluates the two instances of `x` and gets `12`, turns the integer `12` into the String `"12"`, and composes the String "12+12=", which is then printed. (The final "24" we have already addressed above)

Comment: To state the obvious, this is a VERY simplified treatment of this question - it's accurate as far as it goes, but as you learn more about Java and programming, you'll find that there are refinements to this understanding. I hope you enjoy getting there!

Comment: aww i get it now thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: i just learnt java today and my friend who is the one told me to put that (x + "+" + x + "=") bc she got the idea from our vb class and i really dont remember , so yeah thanks again!! @JonKiparsky